# How to delete multiple records in Aerospike given multiple keys through a single AQL query?

Tags: caching, aerospike

I have a list of Aerospike keys with me. I need to delete all the records associated with these keys using [AQL](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql/index.html).

I am aware of the [delete query for a single key](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql/record_operations.html#delete-a-record). Like this:

```
DELETE FROM <ns>[.<set>] WHERE PK=<key>
```

However, I would like to delete them all using [AQL](https://www.aerospike.com/docs/tools/aql/index.html) in a single query. Is there any such query to delete in bulk?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you can do that. How are these keys generated? If there is a pattern to it, then you can write a short python script to generate a text file, which has the delete commands. For example:

```
File: mydelete.txt

DELETE FROM ns1.set1 WHERE PK = 'k1'
DELETE FROM ns1.set1 WHERE PK = 'k2'
etc..
```

Then, in AQL, use the RUN command.

```
aql> RUN 'mydelete.txt'
```

However, if you want to delete **all** the records in a set, you can use TRUNCATE in AQL.

Comment: Owing to the fact that you are a member of Aerospike staff and hence there is indeed no way to bulk delete keys, I am marking your answer as accepted.

Comment: The only recommended way to delete is to use durable deletes (available only in Enterprise Edition). Deletion as part of your data model is not recommended. Use initial expiration time set at the time of creating a record as a way to get rid of the record.